# Google Script to use a cell array and return a list of value from Json API

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I want to use a list of cell on the same column to build a custom url and fetch API data. I wrote the code for a single cell (and single value return) but don't know how to extend to the entire column:

```
function checkAddress() {

  var addresses = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Addresses");
  var baseUrl = 'https://my.api.website/xxxxx&address=';
  var address = addresses.getRange(1, 1);
  var addrID = address.getValue();

  var url = baseUrl.concat(addrID);
  var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = JSON.parse(responseAPI.getContentText());

  var data = [[json.result]];
  var dataRange = addresses.getRange(1, 2, 1, 1);
  dataRange.setValue(data);

}
```

The var addrID is the one that change, and all of them are in the A column; I would like to return the result to the B column on the same row.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to loop through Col A. Try the below Code.

```
function checkAddress() {

  var addresses = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Addresses");
  var baseUrl = 'https://my.api.website/xxxxx&address=';

  var data = addresses.getRange(1, 1,addresses.getLastRow()).getValues();

  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var addrID = data[i][0];
    var url = baseUrl.concat(addrID);
    var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var json = JSON.parse(responseAPI.getContentText());

    var data1 = [[json.result]];
    var dataRange = addresses.getRange(i+1,2,1).setValue(data1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works! I had to change the second "var data" bacause it was already declared, but it warks! Many thanks!